not detecting the size of object using aruco markers
i have a code that uses aruco markers to detect a real-time object recognition, using yolo v8 model, it detects the object but not the size
the code runs and gives this as output : 0: 192x224 1 aloo methi, 91.7ms
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load YOLO model
model_path = 'D:/Food_Images.v1i.yolov8/runs/detect/train/weights/last.pt'
model = YOLO(model_path)

# ArUco definitions
aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
parameters = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()
detector = cv2.aruco.ArucoDetector(aruco_dict, parameters)

# Predict bounding boxes using YOLO
results = model.predict(source='0', show=True)

for result in results:
    boxes = result.boxes
    for box in boxes:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy
        width = x2 - x1
        height = y2 - y1
        print(f'Bounding box size: width={width}, height={height}')
        
        # Detect ArUco markers
        corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = detector.detectMarkers()
        print(f'ArUco marker corners: {corners}')
        print(f'ArUco marker IDs: {ids}')
        
        if ids is not None and len(ids) > 0:
            marker_size = 10  # Size of the marker in centimeters (adjust based on actual marker size)
            pixel_size = corners[0][0][1][0] - corners[0][0][0][0]  # Assuming the marker is a square
            cm_per_pixel = marker_size / pixel_size  
            print(f'cm_per_pixel: {cm_per_pixel}')
            object_size = width * height * cm_per_pixel
            print(f'Object size: {object_size} cm^2')

# Print YOLO results
print(results)

how do i get the object size?
